# Send data from Thread to Activity / Fragment

Tags: android, multithreading, service

In my application I receive a data stream via bluetooth. For this purpose I've created a `BluetoothService` class which has several threads to communicate with the bluetooth device.
In this class I have also a Thread which receives the data from an `InputStream`. The data is received very fast (every 10ms). Receiving of the data stream is working well.

Now I am asking myself how to transport that data to my current activity in order to display (plot) the received data. This should be done in an efficient way. I guess sending broadcasts or somthing like that is too inefficient. Is there some sort of fast event queue or something similar?

How can I send the data from the receiving thread in the service to my activity/fragment?

kind regards

Comment: Hi Moonlit, what framework did you use in the end? I'm at a similar point. I'm receiving 5 bytes every 4ms and can't figure out the most efficient way to make sure I don't drop packets while sending the data from my Bluetooth service thread to my main activity. I plan to use a handler, but not sure if there's a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `runOnUiThread` or you can use `Handler` or you can use `AsyncTask` and the `progressPublish()`method or you can use `post` method of widgets.